# Grouping Controls

Tags: c++, user-interface, grouping, c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 5. Is there a way to group a disparate set of controls so that by simply calling, for instance, `myGroup.Enabled = false;` will set all group of controls `enabled` property to false? I can't use a GroupBox since the controls (labels, checkboxes, etc) are on different `TabPages`.

The reason I ask is so I don't have to call each control's `enabled` property explicitly and can do it with one simple call.

If not, how can I create a custom Control class to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Tag property](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/_!!MEMBERTYPE_Properties_Classes_TComponent_14_Published_Properties.html) of the controls and create your own grouping.

```
void TForm1::SetControlState(TWinControl *WinCtrl, const bool IsEnabled, const int TagValue)
{
 // set the enabled property for each control with matching TagValue
 for (int Index = 0; Index < WinCtrl->ControlCount; ++Index)
 {
   if (WinCtrl->Controls[Index]->Tag == TagValue)
   {
     WinCtrl->Controls[Index]->Enabled = IsEnabled;
   }

   // set child controls
   if (WinCtrl->Controls[Index]->InheritsFrom(__classid(TWinControl)))
   {
     TWinControl *TempWinCtrl;
     TempWinCtrl = static_cast<TWinControl *>(WinCtrl->Controls[Index]);
     SetControlState(TempWinCtrl, IsEnabled, TagValue);
   }
 } // end for
}
```

Alternatively, If you want to enable/disable all controls in one go.

```
void TForm1::SetControlState(TWinControl *WinCtrl, const bool IsEnabled)
{
 // set the enabled property for each control with parent TabSheet
 for (int Index = 0; Index < WinCtrl->ControlCount; ++Index)
 {
   WinCtrl->Controls[Index]->Enabled = IsEnabled;

   // disable child controls
   if (WinCtrl->Controls[Index]->InheritsFrom(__classid(TWinControl)))
   {
     TWinControl *TempWinCtrl;
     TempWinCtrl = static_cast<TWinControl *>(WinCtrl->Controls[Index]);
     SetControlState(TempWinCtrl, IsEnabled);
   }
 } // end for
}
```

**Examples:**

```
// disable all controls on the form
SetControlState(Form1, false);

// disable all controls on a tabsheet
SetControlState(TabSheet1, false);
```

**NOTE:** The above code has been tested with C++Builder 2007

Comment: When comparing the tabsheets, may I ask why you wish to compare by name, and not just compare the pointers? Should be a lot faster.

Comment: @TommyA: Thanks, I've changed the code.  I'm not sure why I was comparing the controls by name.  I copied my first example, so I probably didn't read the code fully.

Comment: @Roboto.  The syntax is correct, however I was not disabling child controls.  I have updated my answer and the code should work.

Comment: Well a recursive structure as you are using now seems obvious. But actually setting a controls Enabled property will already set that of the child controls as well, so there should be no need for it. However it is a good idea to send an initial control, so you are not bound to Form1.

Comment: this seems to work but the controls don't update properly.. i tried calling Update() but no effect.. I change tabs and it refreshes properly.. when I call Enabled explicitly by naming the control, this issue does not happen - weird

Comment: @Roboto: Try Application->ProcessMessages() at the end or adding WinCtrl->Controls[Index]->Invalidate() after the Enabled property is set.

Comment: @stukelly: I'll try that.. I did ->Repaint() and ->Update() which should invalidate the controls.

Comment: @stukelly: It only affects labels that are in nested tabs. Any clues? I followed your suggestions but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Roboto: I have tested with C++Builder 6 and it works with the above code.  What do you mean "labels that are in nested tabs"?

Comment: @stukelly: Take a form, create a pagecontrol, add tabs, now in one tab page, make another set of tabs (like a subsection). The label does not update if it is on one of the nested tab pages.

Answer (score 2):

Since the controls you want to group are not in the same container, then I suggest using a TAction (look at the TActionList component).  All TControl descendants have a public (sometimes even published) `Action` property.  You can have the same TAction object assigned to multiple controls at the same time.  Enabling/disabling the TAction (or updating any of its other properties) will automatically update all associated controls accordingly.