# Faster to Compare by Name or Type?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

When performing an object comparison, is it faster to compare by name (string) or type (pointer)?

See below:

```
if(sender is DataGridView) { .. }
```

or

```
if(sender.GetType().ToString() == "System.Forms.DataGridView") { .. }
```

Note: I may not have the syntax exactly right... this is a C# example, but the [comment answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986392/grouping-controls/1986825#1986825) in one [my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986392/grouping-controls) made me think about it.

Comment: Why did you add the C++ tag? This looks like only C# code

Comment: Because of my linked example.. C# was just an example.. it applies to any language

Comment: Type.ToString() requires digging the name out of the assembly metadata.  That's slow.

Comment: Just write a small console app, let it loop let's say 1e6 times for both cases and display the elapsed times for both using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two aren't equivalent. The second will only be matched if the type of sender is exactly `DataGridView`. The first will be matched if the type is, or inherits from, `DataGridView`. So point one, the comparisons are not the same. As Benjamin Podszun says in his answer, the correct comparison for exact type equality is:

```
instance.GetType() == typeof(Class)
```

That aside, my gut feeling is that type comparison will be faster for sure if the type is exactly `DataGridView`, but that it will be less clear cut in the case where it is a descendant type.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (sender.GetType().ToString() == "System.Forms.DataGridView")
```

should probably better be

```
if (sender.GetType() == typeof(DataGridView))
```

whatever the performance characteristics might be.